# Different Markers in Scatterplot based on Label

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, scatter-plot, markers

I want to scatterplot the validation results of different models and methods. Both the "Train" and "Validation" datapoints are to be plotted in different colors (already done). In addition to that, I'd like to use different markers for the different models, like in the following:

- Model 1, train set: marker *"triangle_down"* in color "red"
- Model 1, validation set: marker *"triangle down"* in color "blue"
- Model 2, train set: marker *"octagon"* in color "red"
- Model 2, validation set: marker *"octagon"* in color "blue"

[The dataframe looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utQRE.jpg)

I have the following body of a function

```
k=1
label=['Train', 'Validation']
drop_learners=[]
drop_cols=[]

train_summary = self_summary_train.drop(drop_learners).drop(drop_cols, axis=1)
validation_summary = self_summary_validation.drop(drop_learners).drop(drop_cols, axis=1)

plot_data = pd.concat([self_summary_train, self_summary_validation])
plot_data['label'] = [i.replace('Train', '') for i in plot_data.index]
plot_data['label'] = [i.replace('Validation', '') for i in plot_data.label]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(12, 8)
xs = plot_data['Abs % Error of ATE']
ys = plot_data['MSE']
group = np.array([label[0]] * self_summary_train.shape[0] + [label[1]] * self_summary_validation.shape[0])
cdict = {label[0]: 'red', label[1]: 'blue'}

for g in np.unique(group):
        ix = np.where(group == g)[0].tolist()
        ax.scatter(xs[ix], ys[ix], c=cdict[g], label=g, s=100)

for i, txt in enumerate(plot_data.label[:]):
        ax.annotate(txt, (xs[i] + 0.005, ys[i]))
        
ax.set_xlabel('Abs % Error of ATE')
ax.set_ylabel('MSE')
ax.set_title('Learner Performance (averaged over k={} simulations)'.format(k))
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.1, 0.5))
plt.show()
```

I already tried in the for-loop to set marker in the scatter-function to

- `markerdict = {learners[0]: ".", learners[1]: 'v', learners[2]: "^", learners[3]: "1", learners[4]: "2", learners[5]: "8", learners[6]: "p",learners[7]:"*", learners[8]:"d"}`
- `markers=['^', 's', 'p', 'h', '8']`
  but it didn't work out.

Maybe someone can help me here, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

See if this will work:

```
markers=['^', 's', 'p', 'h', '8']
for idx, g in enumerate(np.unique(group)):
    ix = np.where(group == g)[0].tolist()
    ax.scatter(xs[ix], ys[ix], c=cdict[g], label=g, s=100, marker = markers[idx])
```